# What is the fastest way to create a checksum for large files in C#

Tags: c#, .net, large-files, checksum

I have to sync large files across some machines. The files can be up to 6GB in size. The sync will be done manually every few weeks. I cant take the filename into consideration because they can change anytime.

My plan is to create checksums on the destination PC and on the source PC and then copy all files with a checksum, which are not already in the destination, to the destination.
My first attempt was something like this:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

private static string GetChecksum(string file)
{
    using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(file))
    {
        SHA256Managed sha = new SHA256Managed();
        byte[] checksum = sha.ComputeHash(stream);
        return BitConverter.ToString(checksum).Replace("-", String.Empty);
    }
}
```

The Problem was the runtime:
- with SHA256 with a 1,6 GB File -> 20 minutes
- with MD5 with a 1,6 GB File -> 6.15 minutes

Is there a better - faster - way to get the checksum (maybe with a better hash function)?

Comment: Do you really need check the Checksum? How are you copying the files? If your on windows I would use the latest version of Robocopy ...

Comment: Nice tip here to only bother hashing if the file sizes are different between 2 candidate files http://stackoverflow.com/a/288756/74585

Answer (score 131, accepted):

The problem here is that `SHA256Managed` reads 4096 bytes at a time (inherit from `FileStream` and override `Read(byte[], int, int)` to see how much it reads from the filestream), which is too small a buffer for disk IO.

To speed things up (2 minutes for hashing 2 Gb file on my machine with SHA256, 1 minute for MD5) wrap `FileStream` in `BufferedStream` and set reasonably-sized buffer size (I tried with ~1 Mb buffer):

```
// Not sure if BufferedStream should be wrapped in using block
using(var stream = new BufferedStream(File.OpenRead(filePath), 1200000))
{
    // The rest remains the same
}
```

Comment: OK - this made the diffence - hashing the 1.6GB file with MD5 took 5.2 seconds on my box (QuadCode @2.6 GHz, 8GB Ram) - even faster as the native implementaion...

Comment: i don't get it. i just tried this suggestion but the difference is minimal to nothing. 1024mb file w/o buffering 12-14 secs, with buffering also 12-14 secs - i understand that reading hundreds of 4k blocks will produce more IO but i ask myself if the framework or the native APIs  below the framework do not handle this already..

Comment: A little late to the party, but for FileStreams there is no longer any need to wrap the stream in a BufferedStream as it is nowadays already done in the FileStream itself. [Source](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brada/2004/04/15/filestream-and-bufferedstream/)

Comment: I was just going through this issue with smaller files (<10MB, but taking forever to get an MD5).  Even though I use .Net 4.5, switching to this method with the BufferedStream cut the hash time down from about 8.6 seconds to <300 ms for an 8.6MB file

Comment: I used a BufferedStream /w 512 kB instead of 1024 kB. The 1.8 GB file was solved in 30 seconds.

Comment: how about CRC32? I know chances of collision will probably increase, but if  we are willing to overlook that aspect, is it faster than MD5/SHA?

Comment: I set the buffer size to the same size as the file being hashed.  Hashing almost 33,000 files went from about 30 minutes to under 1 minute.  The hash loop is run in parallel and the max file size is 128 Megabytes but the smallest is just a few Kilobytes.  RAM usage dropped considerably compared to using a fixed buffer size.

Answer (score 76):

Don't checksum the entire file, create checksums every 100mb or so, so each file has a collection of checksums.

Then when comparing checksums, you can stop comparing after the first different checksum, getting out early, and saving you from processing the entire file.

It'll still take the full time for identical files.

Comment: I like the idea, but it will not work in my scenario because I will end up with a lot of unchanged files over the time.

Comment: A very pessimistic view... ;-)

Comment: how do you checksum every 100mb of a file?

Comment: Very Smart, like your way of thought... will use that in my Duplicate killer app :)

Comment: Not a good idea when using checksum for security reasons, because attacker can just change that bytes you have excluded.

Comment: +1 This is an excellent idea when you are performing a one-to-one comparison.  Unfortunately, I'm using the MD5 hash as an index to look for unique files among many duplicates (many-to-many checks).

Comment: @b.kiener No byte is excluded. You misunderstood him.

Answer (score 57):

[As Anton Gogolev noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1177744/3195477), FileStream reads 4096 bytes at a time by default,
But you can specify any other value using the FileStream constructor:

```
new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite, 16 * 1024 * 1024)
```

Note that Brad Abrams from Microsoft wrote in 2004:

> there is zero benefit from wrapping a BufferedStream around a
>   FileStream.  We copied BufferedStream’s buffering logic into
>   FileStream about 4 years ago to encourage better default performance

[source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2004/04/15/114329.aspx)

Answer (score 23):

Invoke the windows port of [md5sum.exe](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/files/unxutils/current/UnxUtils.zip/download). It's about two times as fast as the .NET implementation (at least on my machine using a 1.2 GB file)

```
public static string Md5SumByProcess(string file) {
    var p = new Process ();
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "md5sum.exe";
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = file;            
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.Start();
    p.WaitForExit();           
    string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    return output.Split(' ')[0].Substring(1).ToUpper ();
}
```

Comment: WOW - using md5sums.exe from pc-tools.net/win32/md5sums makes it really fast. 

1681457152 bytes, 8672 ms = 184.91 MB/sec -> 1,6GB ~ 9 seconds

This will be fast enough for my purpose.

Answer (score 18):

Ok - thanks to all of you - let me wrap this up:

1. [using a "native" exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177607/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-create-a-checksum-for-large-files-in-c/1177712#1177712) to do the
   hashing took time from 6 Minutes to
   10 Seconds which is huge.
2. [Increasing the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177607/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-create-a-checksum-for-large-files-in-c/1177744#1177744) was even faster - 1.6GB file took 5.2 seconds using MD5 in .Net, so I will go with this solution - thanks again

Answer (score 10):

I did tests with buffer size, running this code

```
using (var stream = new BufferedStream(File.OpenRead(file), bufferSize))
{
    SHA256Managed sha = new SHA256Managed();
    byte[] checksum = sha.ComputeHash(stream);
    return BitConverter.ToString(checksum).Replace("-", String.Empty).ToLower();
}
```

And I tested with a file of 29½ GB in size, the results were

- 10.000: 369,24s
- 100.000: 362,55s
- 1.000.000: 361,53s
- 10.000.000: 434,15s
- 100.000.000: 435,15s
- 1.000.000.000: 434,31s
- And 376,22s when using the original, none buffered code.

I am running an i5 2500K CPU, 12 GB ram and a OCZ Vertex 4 256 GB SSD drive.

So I thought, what about a standard 2TB harddrive. And the results were like this

- 10.000: 368,52s
- 100.000: 364,15s
- 1.000.000: 363,06s
- 10.000.000: 678,96s
- 100.000.000: 617,89s
- 1.000.000.000: 626,86s
- And for none buffered 368,24

So I would recommend either no buffer or a buffer of max 1 mill.

Comment: I dont get it. How can this test contradict the accepted answer from Anton Gogolev?

Comment: Can you add description of each field in your data?

Answer (score 4):

I know that I am late to party but performed test before actually implement the solution.

I did perform test against inbuilt MD5 class and also [md5sum.exe](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/files/unxutils/current/UnxUtils.zip/download). In my case inbuilt class took 13 second where md5sum.exe too around 16-18 seconds in every run.

```
    DateTime current = DateTime.Now;
    string file = @"C:\text.iso";//It's 2.5 Gb file
    string output;
    using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
    {
        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(file))
        {
            byte[] checksum = md5.ComputeHash(stream);
            output = BitConverter.ToString(checksum).Replace("-", String.Empty).ToLower();
            Console.WriteLine("Total seconds : " + (DateTime.Now - current).TotalSeconds.ToString() + " " + output);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can have a look to XxHash.Net ( https://github.com/wilhelmliao/xxHash.NET )
The xxHash algorythm seems to be faster than all other.
Some benchmark on the xxHash site : https://github.com/Cyan4973/xxHash

PS: I've not yet used it.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing something wrong (probably too small read buffer). On a machine of undecent age (Athlon 2x1800MP from 2002) that has DMA on disk probably out of whack (6.6M/s is damn slow when doing sequential reads):

Create a 1G file with "random" data:

```
# dd if=/dev/sdb of=temp.dat bs=1M count=1024    
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB) copied, 161.698 s, 6.6 MB/s

# time sha1sum -b temp.dat
abb88a0081f5db999d0701de2117d2cb21d192a2 *temp.dat
```

**1m5.299s**

```
# time md5sum -b temp.dat
9995e1c1a704f9c1eb6ca11e7ecb7276 *temp.dat
```

**1m58.832s**

This is also weird, md5 is consistently slower than sha1 for me (reran several times).

Comment: Yes - I will try to increase the buffer - like Anton Gogolev sugested. I ran it through a "native" MD5.exe which took 9 seconds witth a 1,6 GB file.