# Why does ComputeHash perform much slower then certutil -hashfile?

Tags: c#, hash, filestream, unmanaged, managed

I am looking for efficient way of calculating hash of big files (3GB) and realized that calling Windows certutil with argument `-hashfile` perform hash computation 4 time faster (16 sec) than doing it via `SHA512.Create().ComputeHash` (~60 sec) and I am not really understand such a big differences.

I was trying to 'play' with reading buffer size of `FileStream` but it gives me about 2 sec so not really important optimization.

1) Doing hash computation by ComputeHash:

```
var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
using (var fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Temp\BigFile.dat", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, bufferSize: 1024 * 1024 * 10, options: FileOptions.SequentialScan))
{
    Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(SHA512.Create().ComputeHash(fs)));
}
Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

2) Doing it via certutil

```
var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
var fPath = @"C:\Temp\BigFile.dat";
var p = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(@"certutil", $"-hashfile \"{fPath}\" SHA512") { RedirectStandardOutput = true, UseShellExecute=false});
p.WaitForExit();
Console.WriteLine(p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

I would expect some difference in time due to managed/native nature of code but 16 sec vs 60 looks a bit confusing.

At [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177607/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-create-a-checksum-for-large-files-in-c-sharp) it is also mentioned that native code works much faster but the are no explanation of this difference and I am mostly interested in understanding the difference. I was thinking that in nowadays it shouldnt be such a big difference in such simple example (IO + math?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the fastest way to create a checksum for large files in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177607/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-create-a-checksum-for-large-files-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I don't think this is the duplicate of the question mentioned above.

Comment: Try one of the specific `SHA512` implementations? `SHA512Managed`, `SHA512Cng`, `SHA512CryptoServiceProvider`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three implementations of SHA512 in .NET (and the default depends on `CryptoConfig.AllowOnlyFipsAlgorithms` property):

- "System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512CryptoServiceProvider"
- "System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512Cng"
- "System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512Managed"

It could be that those implementations have different performances. Call `SHA512.Create(string)` with each of those strings, and compare results.

Comment: (Or just do e.g. `new SHA512Cng()`)

Comment: Just check `SHA512Managed` as well, in case `SHA512.Create()` was giving you `SHA512Cng`. Not that I've got particularly high hopes for it, but it's worth making sure.

Comment: There is no `SHA512CryptoServiceProvider.Create` - you're just calling `SHA512.Create()`, which will give you `SHA512Managed` / `SHA512Cng`

Comment: @PavelAsedovski try exactly as written `SHA512.Create(string)`, where `string` is one of the stated above, exactly as written.

Comment: @canton7 I was busy writing and investigating. And failing at it as well. But, here's the comment upvote.

Comment: SHA512.Create("System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512Managed") works as 56 sec but all other givs me about 16 sec. So I can say it is the answer - because this particular implementation is slow and two other - much faster. Thank you!

Comment: `SHA512Managed` is, as the name suggests, implemented in C#. `SHA512CryptoServiceProvider` invokes advapi32.dll, while `SHA512Cng` invokes bcrypt.dll.