# Azure blob upload with content-md5 set

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-blob-storage, azure-cli

Goal: Upload a file to Azure Blob Storage and set MD5 that can be validated when a  user downloads the file.

Using Azure CLI Powershell.

```
Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 .\AutoSetup.zip
Algorithm       Hash                                             Path
---------       ----                                             ----
MD5             693EF0DB938308AC2C362F50F7CB9F9F                 C:\MyFiles\AutoSetup.zip

az storage blob upload --account-name mystorageaccount --container-name mycontainername --file AutoSetup.zip --name Autosetup2.zip --content-md5 693EF0DB938308AC2C362F50F7CB9F9F
Finished[#############################################################]  100.0000%
The MD5 value specified in the request is invalid. MD5 value must be 128 bits and base64 encoded. ErrorCode: InvalidMd5
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>InvalidMd5</Code><Message>The MD5 value specified in the request is invalid. MD5 value must be 128 bits and base64 encoded.
RequestId:9f27334a-801e-0028-6db4-3539c5000000
Time:2020-05-29T12:28:23.7677258Z</Message></Error>
```

**Edit 1:**

I've also attempted getting the hash this way

```
$someFilePath = "C:\MyFiles\AutoSetup.zip"
$md5 = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider
$hash = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($md5.ComputeHash([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($someFilePath)))
Write-Host $hash
69-3E-F0-DB-93-83-08-AC-2C-36-2F-50-F7-CB-9F-9F
```

It seems that no matter what I do, the MD5 that is returned for the file is `693EF0DB938308AC2C362F50F7CB9F9F` but Azure won't take it...

**Edit 2:**

I've generated a random 128-bit string `$B&E)H@McQfTjWnZ` and proceeded to encode it in Base64 which gave me `JEImRSlIQE1jUWZUalduWg==` When I attempt to upload a blob with THAT hash, I get a different error message:

```
The MD5 value specified in the request did not match with the MD5 value calculated by the server. ErrorCode: Md5Mismatch
```

The above makes sense, cause I just created a random 128 bit base64 encoded hash. However, now I am wondering why the Powershell's `Get-FileHash` command gives me what seems to be incorrect?

What can be causing the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try converting the hash into a Base64 encoded string. Something like:

```
$someFilePath = "C:\MyFiles\AutoSetup.zip"
$md5 = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider    
$hash = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($md5.ComputeHash([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($someFilePath)))
Write-Host $hash
8SzzdVQAV4Wdbp8Z9qsczg==
```

Comment: That did the trick!! Thank you! Now my only concern is the performance of `[System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes` - is there a file size limit on this? Right now I am testing with small files; however, realistically this will be used with files of 500mb. Which isn't a lot, I know, but still...

Comment: I haven't really tried it. For large files you can try using `BufferedStream`. See this for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177607/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-create-a-checksum-for-large-files-in-c-sharp.

Comment: I just tried this with a 3.9GB file and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add my own "solution" to this, just in case someone prefers this approach.

**Approach 1** is described in the answer by Gaurav. We read the bytes from the file, compute MD5, and encode it with Base64. This will result in MD5 string that `az storage blob upload` will validate and accept. This seems to be the correct way.

**Approach 2** is to upload the file without setting content-md5 and update it after.

Get MD5 hash

```
Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 .\AutoSetup.zip
Algorithm       Hash                                             Path
---------       ----                                             ----
MD5             693EF0DB938308AC2C362F50F7CB9F9F                 C:\MyFiles\AutoSetup.zip
```

Upload the blob without MD5

```
az storage blob upload --account-name mystorageaccount --container-name mycontainername --file AutoSetup.zip --name Autosetup2.zip
Finished[#############################################################]  100.0000%
```

Update the blob with content-md5. We can write anything we want to it here, so using the MD5 from earlier is fine!

```
az storage blob update --account-name mystorageaccount --container-name mycontainername --name Autosetup2.zip -- content-md5 693EF0DB938308AC2C362F50F7CB9F9F
```

I don't know how correct the 2nd approach is, but it will work nonetheless.

Comment: With 2nd approach, I see two problems: 1) You're making an additional network request so there's a possibility of failure. and 2) Because you are only updating `content-md5` property, all other properties (like `content-type`, `cache-control` etc.) will be overwritten.